# composite key for hive column's for hive-hbase integration

Tags: hive, hbase, hiveql

I have a some data for a specific reading which holds different kinds of data with various data types.  I need to show case the same in a HBase table with Hive-HBase integration.
The problem is with deciding the key for the HBase table because there is no specific column data in those readings which can hold primary key concept but we can have two different column data which together can work as unique with datatype as int and timestamp.

Can anyone please help me with the designing for the Hive table where I can keep data from two column (int and timestamp) as a new column which will hold for HBase key.

Thanks,
Manan

Comment: Do you have any code started?

Comment: code haven't started , but we have data. PFB sample data :
serv_pnt_id pcfc_hr_per_strt_dttm
84481         2009-03-01 00:00:00.0